# Build correct realm Subquery

Tags: c#, realm, subquery

I have 2 tables: Quest and HistoryItem;

Simplified Quest:

```
public class Quest : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MaxRepeats { get; set; }        
}
```

Simplified HistoryIyem:

```
public class HistoryItem : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DateTimeOffset DoneTime { get; set; }

    public Quest Quest { get; set; }
}
```

How to write realm subquery correctly to show all Quests that has been finished less than questItem.MaxRepeats? In case of each finished quest will be added into new HistoryItem.Quest field;

As I understood it's must be something like:

```
_db.Realm.All<Quest>().Filter($"SUBQUERY(HistoryItem, $hi, $hi.Quest).@count > $hi.Quest.MaxRepeats");
```

but it's for some reason does not filter correctly =(

> Realms.Exceptions.RealmException: 'SUBQUERY(HistoryItem, $hi, $hi.Quest).@count > $hi.Quest.MaxRepeats:1:8(8): Invalid predicate.'

This subquery is written based on [documentation](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/releases) sample:

```
realm.All<Person>().Filter("SUBQUERY(Dogs, $dog, $dog.Vaccinated == false).@count > 3");
// find all people who have more than 3 unvaccinated dogs.
```

Maybe, here will be some usefull information [NSPredicateCheatsheet](https://static.realm.io/downloads/files/NSPredicateCheatsheet.pdf) or here [js filter usage samples](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/docs/tutorials/query-language.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish the link between `Quest` and `HistoryItem`:

```
public class Quest : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int MaxRepeats { get; set; } 

    [Backlink(nameof(HistoryItem.Quest))]
    public IQueryable<HistoryItem> HistoryItems{ get; }       
}

public class HistoryItem : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DateTimeOffset DoneTime { get; set; }

    public Quest Quest { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use `LINQ` for querying the Quests:

```
_db.Realm.All<Quest>().Filter("HistoryItems.@count <= MaxRepeats");
```

Comment: Still incorrect predicate... Also I have tried `"SUBQUERY(HistoryItem, $hi, $hi.Quest == Quest).@count <= MaxRepeats"` but still the same result - incorrect predicate...

Comment: `Realms.Exceptions.RealmException: 'No property 'HistoryItem' on object of type 'Quest''`

Comment: so you don't have linking between `Quest` and `HistoryItem`? It will be easier to query if you have the link between them. I'll update my answer with the linking

Comment: HistoryItem have a field HistoryItem.Quest. You can see it in HistoryItem class in my question. So they are linked

Comment: no, I mean the backlink for `HistoryItem` in `Quest`

Comment: hm, no, backlink is absent. There are only direct link in `HistoryItem` to `Quest`

Comment: CMIIW, each finished quest will be added into new `HistoryItem`, right? in that case, the `HistoryItems.Count` in `Quest` class will contains the number of times that quest was done. And you want it to be `less than MaxRepeats`, so if the quest doesn't have `HistoryItems` it will count as true. Unless, you want it to be `equal or more than MaxRepeats`.

Comment: looks like a great solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: no problem. don't forget to accept it, if it's solved your problem :)

Comment: ofc, I will mark it as correct answer. Just after check

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: 'The left-hand side of the LessThanOrEqual operator must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm.` so it will not work. In simplier words: its cannot use Count() method in such context. But your idea was great :)

Comment: Now I have fixed your reply to working code. Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andrew You can do it easily (but little dirty) with LINQ by

```
_db.Realm.All<Quest>().Where(p=>_db.Realm.All<HistoryItem>().Count(u=>U.Quest==p)<p.MaxRepeats)
```

As you can see we have to get HistoryItem.Count first.

Comment: this solution will create additional performance load on the DB, so it's not the best solution in general, but this must work on some little DBs. Thanks for your answer.